# Print array of strings vertically

Tags: arrays, c, string

I know how to print a single string vertically.

```
char test[100] = "test";
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(test);i++){
    printf("%c\n",test[i]);
}
```

Which will give me:

```
t
e
s
t
```

But how can I print an array of strings vertically? For example:

```
char listOfTest[2][10] = {"testing1","quizzing"};
```

So it can return:

```
tq
eu
si
tz
iz
gi
1g
```

Comment: You will need two loops (two-dimensions) with the '\n' at the end of the second loop.

Comment: LearningLinux, What should happen if strings are of unequal length?  (Especially if the 2nd string is longer?)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, in my case, they are always of the same length

Comment: @LearningLinux Kind of dodges the issue.  Input data is not always as advertised.  Robust code handles the unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply print a character from both strings.

(Better to test for the null character rather than repeatedly call `strlen()`.)

```
for(i = 0; listOfTest[0][i] && listOfTest[1][i]; i++) {
  printf("%c%c\n", listOfTest[0][i], listOfTest[1][i]);
}
```

To extend to `n` *strings* ...

```
size_t num_of_strings = sizeof listOfTest/sizeof listOfTest[0];
bool done = false;

for (size_t i = 0; listOfTest[0][i] && !done; i++) {
  for (size_t n = 0; n < num_of_strings; n++) {
    if (listOfTest[n][i] == '\0') {
      done = true;
      break;
    }
    printf("%c", listOfTest[n][i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through the first string and print each character at index i in the first string and the second string till you reach the null terminator of first string

**NOTE**: this only work when string 1 and string2 are equal in length and will need modification for other test cases

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char listOfTest[2][10] = {"testing1","quizzing"};
        int i = 0;
        //loop through string 1 till NULL is reach
        while (listOfTest[0][i])
        {
                //prints char at index i in string 1 and 2
                printf("%c%c\n", listOfTest[0][i], listOfTest[1][i]);

                //increment the index value
                i++;
        }

        return (0);
}
```